# jqGrid - Accessing an array inside a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, jqgrid

my JSON looks like:

```
[{"codDiretor":"123",
  "nomeDiretor":"Nome do Diretor",
  "data":"29/01/2014",
  "documentos":[{"codDocumento":"1", "nomeDocumento":"Primeiro Doc"}, 
                {"codDocumento":"2","nomeDocumento":"Segundo Doc"}]
}]
```

I have a column on my grid called "documentos" to retrieve the array. I'm trying to access it this way:

```
var documentos = $("#grid").jqGrid('getCell', dados, 'documentos');
```

`alert(documentos)` displays `[object Object, object Object]`, which means it "can see" what is in the array, since it has 2 index and it show 2 Object. How can I access it? I tried: `documentos[0].codDocumento` and it shows `undefined`.

Thanks,

Lucas.

Comment: `documentos[0].codDocumento` should work, what is `console.log(documentos[0])`

Comment: @tymeJV
I tried console.log(documentos[0]) and it displayed [. Then I made it:   for(var i=0; i<documentos.length; i++) {
    console.log(documentos[i]);
}. It displayed: [object Object, object Object]. Looks like I need to convert or whatever..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I solved. I could notice that when the grid was being populated, I was receiving a real Object (and not a String with "Object" in it). So that, I use stringify() to convert Object -> String.

```
{name:'codDocumento', width:80, sortable: true, editable: false, jsonmap:"documentos",
 formatter: function (cellvalue) {
     if(cellvalue != null) {
         return JSON.stringify(cellvalue);
     }
     else
         return cellvalue;
     }
}
```

After that, when I want to access it like an array, I convert it from String -> Object.

```
var codDocumento = $("#grid").jqGrid('getCell', dados, 'codDocumento');
var jsonArray = $.parseJSON( codDocumento);
```

With this I can access it with: jsonArray[INDEX].codDocumento

Answer (score 0):

Try the `console.log(data);` command.

In your browser, open the console (usually F12), and the output will be shown there. It is easier debugging than using `alert();`.

In Firefox you might need to install FireBug.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is going to work.  since console.log(documentos[0]) printed a "[" that shows that the data in that cell is just a text string, not an object so you are unable to work it it as an array or an object to find out the contents. 
What are you trying to accomplish here by returning an array ? Typically the grid cell always expects a text response of some sort to print in the cell.

Comment: Yeap.. I thought so: it's actually returning a string not an array of object. I'm trying to fill a text area with the content of the array "documentos" from my json. I'm retrieving the data with a hidden column on my grid, but as I can see it converts the array into a string automatically. Still don't know how to avoid it...

Comment: Why not do any text manipulation required on the backend page and return it as a text string so it can be printed in the text area ?  I typically find it easier to do my manipulation in php rather than javascript anyway so jqgrid just has to dump the contents, not figure out what to do with them.

Comment: What kind of text manipulation? Actually, "documentos" won't be static as is in this example, it'll depends on the register: sometimes the array will have 1 element, sometimes 7, and so on...

Comment: that entirely depends on how you want to display the data. I am saying take the array element that you used to build the json response and in your backend page convert that into a text string with the format you want to display in the grid.  If you can provide an example of how you build the response in your backend and also an example of what you want the data to look like, i can give a better answer on what you can do to manipulate it how you want